# oracle conditional query for a single select statement in a pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, conditional-statements

```
select case when (select LOAN_AMNT from table1 where name = 215) is null or LOAN_AMNT = '0.0'
then select REQUESTED_LOAN_AMOUNT from table2 where name = 215
else select LOAN_AMNT from table1 where wi_name = 215 end as LOAN_AMNT123
```

there are two tables, table1 and table2. Both the tables contains an entry of name = 215(unique). I wanna store loan amount into LOAN_AMNT123 from table1 if and only if the loan amount present in table 1 is not null or is not equals to zero else i wanna fetch REQUESTED_LOAN_AMOUNT from table 2 into LOAN_AMNT123. 
I wanna perform this operation in a single query in my oracle pl/sql block. The query i created is not right, please help me create one such query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `inner join` and `case when` as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN t1.loan_amt IS NULL
             OR t1.loan_amt = 0 THEN
            t2.requested_loan_amount
        ELSE
            t1.loan_amnt
    END AS loan_amnt123
FROM
    table1   t1
    JOIN table2   t2 ON t1.wi_name = t2.name
WHERE
    t1.wi_name = 215
```